TopDesk/ Freemarker ... condition on body not working
I have an action sequence in Topdesk. The first step is delivering a body (or not) ... the second step should only be executed if I have response in the previous step.
That's my response body from the first step.
[{"self":"https://xxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=60dd8a8a6d066300689dbc42","accountId":"60dd8a8a6d066300689dbc42","accountType":"atlassian","emailAddress":"h.h@t.com","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/60dd8a8a6d066300689dbc42/2fbb32d1-6a7b-4d72-8e5d-5053f47fc2e9/48","24x24":"https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/60dd8a8a6d066300689dbc42/2fbb32d1-6a7b-4d72-8e5d-5053f47fc2e9/24","16x16":"https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/60dd8a8a6d066300689dbc42/2fbb32d1-6a7b-4d72-8e5d-5053f47fc2e9/16","32x32":"https://avatar-management--avatars.us-west-2.prod.public.atl-paas.net/60dd8a8a6d066300689dbc42/2fbb32d1-6a7b-4d72-8e5d-5053f47fc2e9/32"},"displayName":"XXXXX YYYYYYY","active":true,"timeZone":"Europe/Berlin","locale":"en_US"}]

I tried different things like ?contains ?size ?seq_contains and even the following thing ... which works fine, when I create Issues in Jira from Topdesk. is not working at the moment
<#if _responses.CheckIfAUserExists??>True<#else>False</#if>

I always get errors like this
Step 2 'StopandReturnifuserexists'
[2024-05-15T22:40:40.363967Z] Starting FreeMarker template processing
[2024-05-15T22:40:40.364963Z] Error while processing FreeMarker template: For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a sequence (ArrayList wrapped into f.t.DefaultListAdapter):
==> _responses.CheckIfAUserExists.body  [in template "action sequence" at line 1, column 75]

I am really driving mad ... and appreciate every help I could get.
Regards
Holger
As described above I tried always ?has_content, ?seg_contains a.s.o.

I don't know Topdesk, but the word _responses suggests that there's multiple of them, hence as the error messages says too, it's a "sequence". So it can't know if the CheckIfAUserExists of which response you want.

Since your response body starts with a square-bracket [ this is an indicator your response body contains an array. As you wish to access the very first array, you should follow up with [0]. Try changing it to something like;
<#if _responses.CheckIfAUserExists.body[0].active = true><#/if>

